# Powerset monad on other categories

Tags: category-theory, monads

The powerset monad $\langle \mathrm{Pow}, \eta, \mu \rangle$ is understood on the category $\mathbf{Set}$ of sets and functions to do the following.

$$\mathrm{Pow} \colon \mathbf{Set} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set} $$

$\mathrm{Pow}$ sends a set to the set of subsets on that set.

This is all quite clear.  Can we seat this monad on other categories?  My first thought is any topos, but we can probably do better, i.e., seat it on a broader class of categories.  What is the broad class and how do you define $\mathrm{Pow}$?

Comment: If $\mathcal{C}$ is a cartesian closed category with a subobject classifier $\Omega$, we can define the functor
$$P : \mathcal{C}^{op} \to \mathcal{C}, ~ X \mapsto [X,\Omega].$$
But I assume you want the covariant version, right?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I think I want just  $P:C \rightarrow C$.  Is this possible?  Is that what is meant by the covariant version?

Comment: The exponential functor is right adjoint to the product functor in any Cartesian closed category. This will induce a monad

Comment: This does work for an arbitrary topos. I’m not sure how you expect to get something that works like power sets but not end up with a topos.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName Doesn't that adjunction give the state monad instead of the powerset monad?

Comment: @MarkSaving The ncatlab page on power objects gives a definition which doesn't require finite limits.  And then, if the category also has epi-mono factorizations (which is automatic in a topos, I don't know about the more general situation), you might be able to define the action on morphisms as well (though I'm not sure if you automatically get functoriality unless you assume some sort of generalization of compatibility of images under pullbacks, to be able to use Yoneda's lemma).